# Spring Data Geo Spatial Query with Mysql

Tags: mysql, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-spatial

My use case is the following :

When user is at a certain location , i need to find all Touchpoints within a certain radius of his location.

My Touchpoint Class looks like this :

```
public class TouchPoint{

    private String pointName;

    private String pointDescription

    @Column(columnDefinition = "POINT")
    private Point location;
}
```

I have the following added in my POM :

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-spatial</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I also have the JPA dialect set for Mysql Spatial extension :

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.mysql.MySQL56SpatialDialect
```

My data gets loaded properly but i am not able to get my hibernate query to work to get all points within a certain radius of a given lat,long.

I am not sure how i can get the within query to work with Spring data jpa.

Comment: Can you add the exact hibernate query to get the points within a radius?